# Application Defined Error while creating Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an VBA code to generate a Pivot table, my code works well with other sheet, but in this sheet it is always creating an error. I checked the column Name, sheet Name everyting, still I could not figure out where I am making mistake. I even recorded macro to crosscheck, still i am clueless.

```
Sub AutoPivot7()

Dim ws7 As Worksheet
Dim pc7 As PivotCache
Dim pt7 As PivotTable
Dim ct7 As Integer
Set ws7 = Sheets("Pivot_Reasons")


Set pc7 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'Reasons for Delay'!R1C1:R1048576C2")

Set pt7 = pc7.CreatePivotTable(ws7.Range("B3"))

pt7.AddDataField pt7.PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay"), "Sum of Reasons for Delay", xlSum

With pt7

With .PivotFields("Reasons for Delay")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Reasons for Delay"

End With

With .PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay")
.Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
End With
End With
End Sub
```

The error occurs in the line

> pt7.AddDataField pt7.PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay"), "Sum of
>   Reasons for Delay", xlSum

if i remove this and run my code, i am not getting the error. I also have attached the record macro which i reffered

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-21, -1).Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable44", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable44").PivotFields("Reasons for Delay")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable44").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable44").PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay"), _
        "Sum of Sum of Reasons for Delay", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable44").PivotFields("Reasons for Delay"). _
        AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Sum of Reasons for Delay"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable44").PivotFields( _
        "Sum of Sum of Reasons for Delay")
        .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
        .NumberFormat = "0,00%"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I doubt your field is already called "Sum Of..." so use: `pt7.AddDataField pt7.PivotFields("Reasons for Delay"), "Sum of Reasons for Delay", xlSum`

Comment: @Rory beat me to it (I was trying to post as answer)

Comment: @Rory still the error exist.

Comment: It works for me assuming the field name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:
pt7.AddDataField pt7.PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay"), "Sum of Reasons for Delay", xlSum
to:
pt7.AddDataField pt7.PivotFields("Sum of Reasons for Delay"), "Reasons for Delay", xlSum

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .StatusBar = "!!! Please Be Patient...Updating Records !!!"
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
End With
'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Pivot_Reasons")
'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="FilteredPivotTable")
'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), 
TableName:="FilteredPivotTable")
'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FilteredPivotTable").PivotFields("Reasons for 
Delay")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
End With
'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FilteredPivotTable").PivotFields("Reasons for 
Delay")
 .Orientation = xlDataField
 .Position = 1
 .Function = xlSum
 .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
 .Name = "Reasons"
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FilteredPivotTable").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Reasons"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FilteredPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FilteredPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .StatusBar = False
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```